# Not able to locate an autocomplete field . Received error : Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, autocomplete

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvIIg.png)

Hi ,

Can someone please help me?I'm trying to locate an autocomplete field , but I'm received the error "  Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[contains(@name,'q')] "

I'm using selenium webdriver and I have tried the following xpaths :

-> `//input[contains(@name,'q')]"))).build().perform();`

-> `//nav[contains(@class='navbar-default') and contains(@role='search')];`

->   `//*[@class='navbar-collapse']/form/div/span/input`

-> `//input[contains(@class,'tt-input') and contains(@placeholder,'Search Currencies')];`

->   `//input[contains(@role,'search')and contains(@class,'quick-search-box')];`

Many thanks in advance .

Comment: Could you please provide code of the element you are trying to click? Preferably a link to the page where its on?

Comment: Hi , I've added a link with the capture above the description , but probably is not working .  Here is the capture                         https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvIIg.png

Comment: Its possible that the autocomplete values are within the span under it, class=tt-dropdown-menu. Could you expand and share that?

Comment: Here is the class = tt-dropdown-menu expanded                                                         <span class="tt-dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none; right: auto;">
<div class="tt-dataset-currencies"></div>